# Truncate trailing zeros datagridview column

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, datagridview, formatting

I use a windows datagridview to access data from an order items table in SQL.

I store the price of the item in SQL as decimal(18,4)

On the datagridview I originally used a format string of C4 on the decimal(18,4)

This was fine but it displayed extra zeros on the price if the price was for example just a straight £18.12 it would show it as £18.1200, but if the price is £18.1234 then I want to see £18.1234.  An important note is that I want the £ sign to be culture specific.  As I live in the UK its £, if a US user uses the system it needs to be $ etc etc

The way I got around this was to handle the cell formatting event on the datagridview like so

```
    Private Sub gridOrderItems_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles gridOrderItems.CellFormatting
    If Me.gridOrderItems.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    Dim dr As DataGridViewRow = Me.gridOrderItems.Rows(e.RowIndex)
    If e.ColumnIndex = Me.gridOrderItems.Columns("priceColumn").Index Then
    e.Value = USEFUL.RemoveTrailingZerosForCurrency(e.Value)
    End If
    End If
    End Sub


    Public Shared Function RemoveTrailingZerosForCurrency(ByVal d As Decimal) As String
    Dim s As String = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol
    Return d.ToString(s & "0.00###########################")
    End Function
```

I have started encountering performance issues with painting large datagrids though.  I am busy reading the Microsoft best practices.

I am trying to see if there is a standard way of doing this with possibly just a standard DataGridViewCellStyle Format String. I was going to create a variable to hold the cell style and apply a format to it.

I could use "0.00###########################" but that doesn't include a culture specific Money symbol like £, $ etc

I hope I have explained myself.

### Quick overview

If the price is £18.1234 I want to see £18.1234
If the price is £18.1230 I want to see £18.1230 as it is.
If the price is £18.1200 I want to see £18.12
If the price is £18.0000 I want to see £18.00

and most importantly I want the culture symbol to be culture specific.

I was thinking of changing the SQL datatype to "money" but I might get into a whole load of SQL Cast nightmares if it cant union a decimal(18,4) to a money on our reporting system.

Any ideas or recommendations would be helpful, thanks in advance.

David.

Comment: Have you tried `d.ToString("C4", New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"))` ?

Comment: Ill try it, I worry that 18.0000 will still be 18.0000 by looking at the code

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Public Shared Function RemoveTrailingZerosForCurrency(ByVal d As Decimal) As String
    Return d.ToString("C4").Replace("00", "")
End Function
```

since `ToString` will use [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) if you do not specify a culture.

Comment: Does that means there isn't really a Format string which can do this without manually intercepting the CellFormattingEvent like I am already doing? This is slightly better than what I have.  Im thinking if I Dim a variable of type DataGridViewCellStyle and then set the format of d.ToString("C4").Replace("00", "") and then apply it to the relevant columns, that might speed up performance since im not interfering with every cell style on the cell formatting event.  (id worry this solution you presented might replace 1800.4500 with 18.45 though looking at it.  Thanks.

Comment: Does this not introduce the risk of replacing 12.0034 with 12.34?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating default cell style variables in the form and assigning a style to multiple columns which needed the same type.  I believe this should speed up performance.

At the top of the form declare a symbol for ease of use

```
Private symbol As String = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol
```

Then call this as early as possible, you could do it in form load but im investigating if there is an earlier, and better time before the grid is actually drawn.

```
blackDefaultCellStyle = New DataGridViewCellStyle
blackDefaultCellStyle = Me.gridOrderItems.DefaultCellStyle.Clone()
blackDefaultCellStyle.Format = symbol & "0.00###########################"
```

Now I just assign the column to the cell style like so:

```
Me.gridOrderItems.Columns("DailypriceDataGridViewTextBoxColumn").DefaultCellStyle =  blackDefaultCellStyle
```